# Embedding frameworks inside closed-source Swift framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Our company wants to distribute a closed-source SDK for iOS to our clients. I've been using Cocoapods to build the framework and built an example app making use of it. Previously the app worked fine on the simulator as well as when deployed on the device. However, I was also embedding the Pods.framework file in the app itself. One other piece of information that may be of interest is that the framework is written in Swift, the included cocoapods dependencies are both Swift and Objective-C.

I wanted to make the pods requirements easier to manage so the user doesn't need to be concerned with them and tried to embed the Pods.framework file inside of the SDK we're building - so I removed the steps to **Embed Pods Frameworks** and **Copy Pods Resources** from the example app, leaving them only in the framework, I also removed Pods.framework as a dependency of the example app, leaving it only in the SDK. This seemed to work in the simulator, but the app now crashes on mobile device with **dyld: Library not loaded** error.

Upon researching it, I stumbled into a few related discussions:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/344 https://objectpartners.com/2014/06/25/developing-private-in-house-libraries-with-cocoapods/

However, the suggested solution of using private pods does not look like it would work for us, it's my understanding that the source code in the private pod would still be open, and we can't share it with our clients.

Could someone advise on a solution that would work in this case?

Comment: I had the same exact issue as you not too long ago and gave up due to frustration. Actually, it was around the same time.  Unfortunately I found no solution. Luckily I was early in development of my framework so I changed it to Objective-C so it could be closed source. I then ditched Pods and just imported the 1 framework it needed into its project.

Comment: I think your first link may not be the one you intended. It links to a pie chart library. Did you ever figure out how to do this? There's a good deal of documentation on how to make a private cocoapod, but none that I can find about making a closed source cocoapod - or at least none that aren't incredibly vague.

Comment: You're right, the link seems to be unrelated, I probably linked a wrong CocoaPod issue by mistake, unfortunately I don't remember the original one I meant. I did figure this out, and can post my solution, although it's fragile and requires some hoop jumping.

Comment: I'm having the same kind of issue you describe, could you post your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OK, I finally have a more durable solution. It's a modified, cleaner version of my old one now that I understand how Xcode links in my Swift sub-frameworks better**

Problem that makes distribution/compilation a bit ugly:

Since Swift standard libraries aren't bundled on the device like Obj-C, nor are they guaranteed to be stable between versions yet (stable binary interface promised in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution#development-major-version--swift-30) we have to make sure the entire project is compiled against the same version of Swift. That means the guy using your closed-source framework has to be using the same version of Swift in their Xcode for their project as you did for compiling the library, even if he's not using Swift in his code because ultimately it's his version of Swift that gets bundled into the app and your SDK runs against. This is only an issue for closed-source frameworks because open-source ones will always be compiled against the same version as final project. Possible workaround is to restrict clients to same version you use or distribute multiple compilations (i.e. Swift 2.1 and Swift 2.0). To remedy this, you could provide users with copies of binaries compiled against multiple versions of Swift.

Aside from that, here is what I had to do during compilation/distribution to make a binary framework that works in Swift:

**When building the framework:**

- In project target, make sure to add *Pods.framework* to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** (make sure this is a pre-compiled RED version of Pods.framework, I had a black compiled Pods.framework in the same directory which built fine but then resulted in a framework that would cause the project to complain about missing armv7 architecture during linker phase in later project)
- In Build Settings, under **User-Defined** section, add a field called **BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE** and set it to *bitcode*
- DO NOT `#import` any frameworks in your bridging header, all instructions telling you to do that are leftover from Swift 1.0-1.2 days, you don't need it anymore and it does more harm than good (the later project will complain that it can't find these headers that aren't even exposed to it)
- Change build target to *Generic iOS Device*, **Archive** and **Export** the framework

**When building the project using the framework:**

- Drag and drop the framework into the project, in General tab add it to **Embedded Binaries** and **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** (you only need to add the framework itself, not the sub-frameworks or the pods file)
- In Build Settings tab, add a new path to **Framework Search Paths**: *$(PROJECT_DIR)/MyFramework.framework/Frameworks*
- Build the project

Comment: I don't understand how this solves your swift versioning issue. What happens if your customer is using swift 2.3 and your framework is compiled against 3.0?

Comment: In that same paragraph, the two sentences directly after explain the 2 possible workarounds. Aside from that there is no good solution until Swift stops procrastinating on standardizing their ABI.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov you can distribute one compiled framework for each and every Swift version.  That can be automated.

Comment: @Demi isn't that the same as my second workaround ("distribute multiple compilations (i.e. Swift 2.1 and Swift 2.0)")?

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov It is.  I was just pointing out that this can be 100% automated and should not require much recurring effort.